# With the azure Python SDK, how do I use the ServiceBusManagementClient to send a message on a topic?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm using Python 3.8 with azure-mgmt-servicebus= v. 1.0.0.  Using the ServiceBusManagementClient, I'm able to create a topic and subscription on my service bus, using

```
  from azure.mgmt.servicebus import ServiceBusManagementClient
...
        credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(self._client_id, self._client_secret, tenant=self._tenant)
        sb_client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential, self._subscription)
    sb_client.topics.create_or_update(resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name, parameters={})
        sb_client.subscriptions.create_or_update(resource_group_name, namespace_name, topic_name, SB_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, parameters={})
```

However, I am having a more challenging time sending a message on that topic.  I tried this

```
    credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(self._client_id, self._client_secret, tenant=self._tenant)
sb_client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential, self._subscription)
topic_client = sb_client.get_topic(topic_name)
              topic_client.send(msg)
```

But I get an error "Instance of 'ServiceBusManagementClient' has no 'get_topic' member".  How do I use the ServiceBusManagementClient to send a message on a topic?

Answer (score 0):

To answer directly, `ServiceBusManagementClient` is not for sending a message to a topic.

But have no fear!  The issue here is that you're utilizing functionality from two distinct ServiceBus clients that do not exist in the same package, and this can be sorted out.

1. `ServiceBusManagementClient` is part of the `azure-mgmt-servicebus` package, and allows creation, administration, management, etc. (this is where `create_or_update` and friends come in)
2. `ServiceBusClient` is part of the `azure-servicebus` package, and provides the sending/receiving functionality you seem to want after via `get_topic` and `send`.  (this is the syntax from version 0.5*)

So to be clear, one would not use the `ServiceBusManagementClient` to send messages, only do management.  `ServiceBusClient` is the solution, as seen in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/servicebus_v0.50.3/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/topic_send.py).

Comment: The issue I'm running into is ServiceBusManagementClient is instantiated using a ServicePrincipalCredentials object and a subscription ID.  I'm not clear how to use that information to instantiate a ServiceBusClient.  Could you provide some guidance on that part?

Comment: Of course, and apologies for the slow followup, we've been heads down for some releases coming up:  `ServiceBusClient` version `0.5*` will not be able to use that credential. However, the upcoming GA release,  `7.0.0`, currently in preview, will support azure-identity based authentication (`b8` coming out next week, with final release hopefully not too long after), see [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/client_identity_authentication.py).